# Erase text in PDF file

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I've been using PDFSharp to merge PDF files. But here my problem is some of my document contains page number (say "1 of 2") but merge it after a PDF file (say 1st PDF has 2 pages with correct page numbers 1 of 2, 2 of 2) now again in third page the index is again "1 of 3", "1 of 2" etc. So, how to remove all page numbers and give correct index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
you have to edit existing docs:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1491&view=next

2.
then you need to create a blank pdf doc, and copy the edited ones into the new one
like so:
[PDFsharp edit a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647872/pdfsharp-edit-a-pdf-file)