How to add text to an existing PDF with PDFSharp
Using PDFSharp (1.50 or 6.1.0 Preview 2) I'm trying to open an existing pdf, add some text, then save it again.
However at the line that draws the text I'm getting a System.ArgumentException "An item with the same key has already been added."
I do not understand what this error is trying to tell me or how to resolve it.
Commenting out DrawString line allows the new pdf to be writen, but how do I add text to the PDF?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Fonts;

namespace MakeAPDF
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            const string outfilename = @"C:\Test\Out.pdf";
            PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(@"C:\Test\In.pdf",PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);
            
            // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
            PdfPage page = document.Pages[0];

            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
            // Create a font

            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);
        
            // Draw the text
            // This line triggers System.ArgumentException
            // Message=An item with the same key has already been added.
            gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),  XStringFormats.Center);
        
            // Save the document...  
            document.Save(outfilename);
        }
    }
}

STACKTRACE:
 System.ArgumentException
 HResult=0x80070057
 Message=An item with the same key has already been added.
 Source=mscorlib
 StackTrace: 
 at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
 at PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfResourceMap.CollectResourceNames(Dictionary`2 usedResourceNames)
 at PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfResources.ExistsResourceNames(String name)
 at PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfResources.get_NextExtGStateName()
 at PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced.PdfResources.AddExtGState(PdfExtGState extGState)
 at PdfSharp.Drawing.Pdf.PdfGraphicsState.RealizeFillColor(XColor color, Boolean overPrint, PdfColorMode colorMode)
 at PdfSharp.Drawing.Pdf.PdfGraphicsState.RealizeBrush(XBrush brush, PdfColorMode colorMode, Int32 renderingMode, Double fontEmSize)
 at PdfSharp.Drawing.Pdf.PdfGraphicsState.RealizeFont(XFont font, XBrush brush, Int32 renderingMode)
 at PdfSharp.Drawing.Pdf.XGraphicsPdfRenderer.Realize(XFont font, XBrush brush, Int32 renderingMode)
 at PdfSharp.Drawing.Pdf.XGraphicsPdfRenderer.DrawString(String s, XFont font, XBrush brush, XRect rect, XStringFormat format)
 at PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.DrawString(String text, XFont font, XBrush brush, XRect layoutRectangle, XStringFormat format)

UPDATE:
I've discovered that the above code works if the PDF I start with is either completely empty or only contains shapes. If the PDF already contains just a single piece of text, then this exception is triggered. So this may be a bug in PDFSharp?
The PDF that triggers the issue can be downloaded from here.

I tried the latest version, but that's throwing errors on the XFont line, saying that no font could be resolved.

@IlikedtheoldStackOverflow I've been able to get the fonts working with 6.1.0 Preview 2 now, However I find that this version also produces the same exception regarding "An Item with the same key..." Is this a bug with PDFSharp? or is this not the correct approach to add text to a PDF?

Are there "layers" in a PDF you need to consider?

This is the correct approach and should work with many PDF files, even those containing text. A template for issue reporting is available here: https://docs.pdfsharp.net/General/Issue-Reporting.html

@IlikedtheoldStackOverflow, I do not beleive that the PDFs are "corrupt" , they are created with a graphics packaged called Xara, and they open perfectly fine, there are no duplicate keys in the PDF, but it seems that PDFSharp tries to create a Key that has already been used in the PDF thus triggering this exception. I would have expected PDFSharp to be smarter about the key names it is choosing.

@IlikedtheoldStackOverflow Instead writing to a corrupt file, is it possible to copy the page to a new document and write new text there? I've seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649357/2516718

@IlikedtheoldStackOverflow, Thanks, I understand now, I've edited the simple test PDF in a hex editor, to change the third R1 to R3, and that code then works. As you say Xara is creating a non-standard PDF, I'll log a bug with them, buf their not the best at fixing issues.

@derloopkat, I'll try copying the page to a new page, and will report back

@derloopkat, Unfortunately trying the copy page to a new page I get the same exception on the new page, so I guess PDFSharp is copying the keys verbatim in to the new page.

This was a bug in PDFsharp up to version 6.1.0 Preview 2.
The bug was fixed with PDFsharp version 6.1.0 Preview 3, released today.
The check for duplicate resource names in PDFsharp was too strict and prevented those files from opening.
PDFsharp was published about 20 years ago and this issue had not been reported before

That's great news!, Thanks PDFSharp for the quick fix. I've tested preview 3 and it's working perfect with these PDFs now.
